# ProtonVPN Autostart configuration error

Tags: vpn, kubuntu, autostart

I am trying to make ProtonVPN autostart on my Kubuntu machine.

I have tried following [this](https://blog.x86txt.com/articles/protonvpn-cli-systemd.html) and [this](https://github.com/ProtonVPN/protonvpn-cli-ng/blob/master/USAGE.md#auto-connect-on-boot) guides.

The latest one I tried is the one from blog.x86txt.com. But when using the following command:

```
systemctl enable protonvpn-cli.service && systemctl start protonvpn-cli.service
```

I get the following message from the terminal:

```
Job for protonvpn-cli.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status protonvpn-cli.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When i run the comand

```
systemctl status protonvpn-cli.service
```

I get the following output:

```
 ● protonvpn-cli.service - ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/protonvpn-cli.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-01-13 11:19:20 CET; 13s ago
  Process: 2177 ExecStart=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli last-connect (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[2177]: protonvpn-cli.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/protonvpn-cli
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jan 13 11:19:20 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start.
log file: -binfmt_misc.automount  protonvpn-cli.service
```

Teuton is the users name.

I will paste my systemd file down below.

```
[Unit]
Description=ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=teuton
ExecStart=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli last-connect
ExecReload=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect && /usr/bin/protonvpn-cli last-connect
ExecStop=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here i removed the `--` in the commands `--last-connect` and `--disconnect` from blog.x86txt.com to see if it would help me in any way.

Edit:

Here is the `journalctl -xe` output:

```
-- Subject: Unit anacron.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit anacron.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
jan 13 14:04:47 teuton-VirtualBox anacron[1883]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-01-13
jan 13 14:04:47 teuton-VirtualBox anacron[1883]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
jan 13 14:17:01 teuton-VirtualBox CRON[1896]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
jan 13 14:17:01 teuton-VirtualBox CRON[1897]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
jan 13 14:17:01 teuton-VirtualBox CRON[1896]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
jan 13 14:20:16 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
-- Subject: Unit motd-news.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit motd-news.service has begun starting up.
jan 13 14:20:16 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
-- Subject: Unit motd-news.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit motd-news.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
jan 13 15:05:08 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
-- Subject: Unit anacron.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit anacron.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.                                                                                                                   
jan 13 15:05:08 teuton-VirtualBox anacron[1959]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-01-13                                                                  
jan 13 15:05:08 teuton-VirtualBox anacron[1959]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)                                                                           
jan 13 15:17:01 teuton-VirtualBox CRON[1969]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
jan 13 15:17:01 teuton-VirtualBox CRON[1970]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
jan 13 15:17:01 teuton-VirtualBox CRON[1969]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
jan 13 15:24:32 teuton-VirtualBox sudo[1983]:   teuton : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/etc/systemd/system ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/visudo
jan 13 15:24:32 teuton-VirtualBox sudo[1983]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by teuton(uid=0)
jan 13 15:42:02 teuton-VirtualBox sudo[1983]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

teuton@teuton-VirtualBox:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl enable protonvpn-cli.service && systemctl start protonvpn-cli.service
[sudo] lösenord för teuton:
Job for protonvpn-cli.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status protonvpn-cli.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
teuton@teuton-VirtualBox:/etc/systemd/system$ journalctl -xe
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[2085]: protonvpn-cli.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/protonvpn: No such process
-- Subject: Process /usr/bin/protonvpn could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The process /usr/bin/protonvpn could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is 3.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=217
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start.
-- Subject: Unit protonvpn-cli.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit protonvpn-cli.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit protonvpn-cli.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start.
-- Subject: Unit protonvpn-cli.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit protonvpn-cli.service has finished shutting down.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: protonvpn-cli.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jan 13 15:42:25 teuton-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start ProtonVPN CLI Auto-Start.
-- Subject: Unit protonvpn-cli.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit protonvpn-cli.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
lines 2394-2435/2435 (END)
```

Edit 2: here is my `sudo visudo` output:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
teuton ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/protonvpn
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the commands from your startup script manually to see if they work? The information from the journalctl is not really sufficient to properly troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, it seems like the commands does not work, i tried sudo protonvpn c -f aswell and that worked.

I believe there might also be something wrong with my aliases and sudo password query, as i always need to execute the program as root, i will redo the journalctl -xe and also add my sudo visudo.

Answer (score 0):

The path and executable file in your systemd unit configuration do not match what you have in your sudoers.d file.

The `sudoers.d` file mentions `/usr/local/bin/protonvpn` (note the `local` and no `-cli` extension after `protonvpn`), which seems correct to me, as it is both what ProtonVPN.com indicates in the instructions you listed in your question, and what I have on my own machine. (I cannot check your first link, it appears to be dead).

On the other hand the systemd unit description lists `/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli` (no `local`, but a `-cli` extension):

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli last-connect  
ExecReload=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect && /usr/bin/protonvpn-cli last-connect  
ExecStop=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect*
```

What prompted me to look into this direction is your log: systemd seems not able to launch the requested program on ExecStart:

```
Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/protonvpn-cli
```

and then it directly goes into error.

You should check what the correct path and executable file is on your machine by running the commands `which protonvpn` and `which protonvpn-cli`. For me only the first one returns a path, and it is `/usr/local/bin/`.

Update both your sudoers.d and systemd unit configuration with the correct file and path as determined in the previous step.

**Side Note**
I would recommend being more specific in your sudoers.d file. Right now having user privilege is enough to fully control your VPN (including turning it off, or disabling the kill switch). Best to only grant no-password access to the specific commands `protonvpn connect` and `protonvpn reconnect`. Here's how the line would look like (assuming /usr/local/bin/protonvpn is the right path):

```
teuton ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/protonvpn connect,/usr/local/bin/protonvpn reconnect
```

Then in the systemd unit configuration:

1. replace the `ExecReload=` commands you currently have by `/usr/local/bin/protonvpn reconnect`, which in effect does the exact same thing with the advantage of not having to allow the `disconnect` command.
2. remove entirely your `ExecStop=/usr/bin/protonvpn-cli disconnect` line. It is unneeded (at shutdown your VPN will get disconnected anyway, as it does on my machine without this line).

Now you don't need the disconnect command any longer in your sudoers.d file, and you've just increased security on your machine!
;-)